# How would one construct a NxN crossbar switch from solid state components?

Tags: relay, multiplexer, solid-state-relay, switching

I was trying to construct a 10x10 cross bar switch using relays -- something like:

[image]

Question: is it possible to construct this by using solid state components (power transistors?) -- and if it is how would one go about doing it?

Would appreciate any pointers.

NOTES:

1. The target application was to be able to wire together discreet analog components: say OpAms, diodes, transistors
2. I was trying to build a hybrid analog-digital computer -- just for fun -- where the digital side would wire together the analog components using a crossbar switch. Using relays becomes very expansive very quickly say if I wanted to have a 100x100 crossbar.
3. An attempt at specs: V=36V, Imax = 10mA R ~= 0 (approaching zero -- a few Ohms should be fine) f ~= 0 Hertz [you switch once every few seconds or minutes] -- Note these are what I think would be ideal, a subset or partially covering set should do for now too
4. So I the cross-bar or equivalent switching fabric could be an Integrated Circuit
5. The Analog components (discreete) that the will connected to the switching fabric will include: Resistors, Capacitors, OpAms, Transistors, Diodes, Differential Amps, Voltage Summers (if I remember from my undergrad?)
6. A typical example of circuit that I want to wire together using such a cross bar is below:

[image]

Comment: Why would it not be possible?

Comment: V,I  or V,R specs are missing

Comment: Since you do not give much requirements I agree with PlasmaHH, it is possible. Andy shows an IC with such a matrix. A limitation of that IC is that the voltage (differences) on the switching nodes are limited. You do not mention any requirement for that. A relay implementation does not care about the voltages. Instead of electromechanical relays you could use solid state relays.

Comment: @FakeMoustache -- thanks for the comment -- I updated the question. I'm trying to use the crossbar to be able to wire together elementary circuit components -- the idea is to build a simple analog/digital hybrid computer

Comment: @TonyStewart -- sorry about that Tony - I'm a bit hazy on my circuit design -- I've updated the question with the target application in mind -- hope that helps

Comment: @user1172468 you might want to specify how much you want to construct this from (discrete) components. The answer you accepted is about options for monolithic chips that implement the desired function. If this is acceptable, you may want to reword your question.

Comment: Still need specs for V,R and f of each switch oor switch times

Comment: @TonyStewart -- made a crude attempt at V, R and f -- hope it is in the right direction

Comment: @user2943160 updated the question -- hope it clarifies

Comment: `R=0` is impossible. The specification really is how much resistance can you tolerate and how much variation between channels needs to be limited.

Comment: then spec load current, and delta R, this limits the choice of solutions or spec Vout(sat) max

Comment: @user2943160 -- updated the question to R ~=0 approaching zero as in a few Ohms would be fine for my application

Comment: So does Vds=0.4V at 40mA satisfy this or 100mA or is it +/-12 across switch

Comment: So is this unipolar switch , ie.current in one direction only or bipolar or analog bilateral switch using HV CMOS. (specs are critical to design)

Comment: @TonyStewart -- the more I think about it -- I guess unipolar will work for solving differential equations

Comment: @TonyStewart more like 100mA or is it +/-12 across I think

Comment: it will simplify design if you think about specs more for all applications, make it realistic

Comment: @TonyStewart -- I pasted in the question an exemplar schematic that I'd like to implement.

Comment: Ok , looks like an analog computer cross point switch high impedance 25V min

Comment: @TonyStewart yup -- I'd like to be able to create something like that ... so the wiring of the components would be done by the cross-bar like fabric

Comment: this rules out all Andy's research since specs have changed. HIs analog switch is -~12V

Comment: @TonyStewart -- so if I limit my V to 12V -- does that mean I can use MT8816?

Comment: yes single 13.2 supply V/2 bias for 12Vpp, 65 Ohm delta 10 max $18 DIP40

Comment: @TonyStewart many thanks for the help :-) -- I read about Hybrid computers when I was in 2nd grade and have been on my bucket list

Comment: We used them in labs in Univ. for Simulating closed loop servo and temp control systems using cross point wires...erhaps 44 yrs ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would appreciate any pointers

The MT8816 is an analogue cross point switch: -

[image]

The ISL59532 is a video cross point switch: -

[image]

Ditto the HA456: -

[image]

There is also the ADV3202: -

[image]

Or, you could just roll your own using [analogue switches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analogue_switch) wired into a matrix.

Comment: oh wow -- many thanks -- I was looking at the data sheet of the MT8816 -- does a multiplexed circuit essentially act like a copper wire within its operating region -- forgive the lay speak, it's been a couple of decades since I was in school?

Comment: An analogue switch might have an on-resistance of several ohms to several tens of ohms and an off-resistance of several Mohms so it's not as good as a relay contact. OMRON produce some very nice (and small) solid state relays that are effectively isolated and offer sub-ohm on resistance.

Comment: Several ohms I think would be fine -- what about the inductance (I take it that would be zero for a solid state component) or capacitance

Comment: I also updated the question -- I'm trying to create a system that wires together discrete components for the purposes of a simple analog computer

Comment: It will be low and definitely sub micro henries. Open circuit capacitance can be quite high and this could be a limitation but try finding the OMRON devices I mentioned.

Comment: OMRON link to SSR: https://www.omron.com/ecb/products/pry/114/g3vm_21pr1.html

Comment: saw those -- they are unfortunately price -- Analog Diodes would be cheaper. I would like something more along the lines of MT8816 in terms of price and density

Comment: Try googling "analogue cross-point switch"

Comment: +1 from me for all the hard work you put into that excellent answer