# In a multiplexer, can you direct the input into all the outputs at the same time?

Tags: multiplexer

I need to direct a single line into multiple outputs, so I'm using a MUX to direct the input into the desired outputs (one at a time). However if i ever wanted to do a broadcast to all my output lines at the same time, is there any MUX which allows it ? Can I connect the input to ALL the outputs directly? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look into analog switches, or transmission gates. You will need one control wire for each output.

Comment: What does the data sheet for your mux say?

Comment: (1) In principles, broadcast is possible.  In practice, this depends on the specific implementation of the mux/switch.  So, I second @Dave's comment.  (2) "*is there any MUX which allows it?*" is a wrong sort of question for EE.SE .  We don't make recommendations.  (Even if we did, the question doesn't even contain enough information to make a recommendation.)

Comment: Are you willing to consider oddball solutions? Or is this just a general question where a specific solution isn't helpful? An externally modified 74159 could achieve this, for example.

Comment: Hi, sorry for mi late reply, but yeah if you have some oddball solution it will be welcome. Thank u everyone, so far I haven't pick a MUX yet, but every one I saw lacked the broadcast feature, I'll keep looking ;)

Comment: What kind of signals are these.  Analog, or digital?  What frequency?  What voltage?  Is there any type of signaling standard you are following (Audio, Video, Serial data, etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functionality you appear to require appears to be serviced by what is called a cross-point switch. Usually they have several inputs and several outputs that form an open matrix. Loading a specific code word can connect one input to several outputs simultaneously. They are rarer than multiplexers but they do exist.

[image]

The part is shown in [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/256893/how-would-one-construct-a-nxn-crossbar-switch-from-solid-state-components/256898?s=1|0.5474#256898) question answered by me.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, this is actually very helpful, I forgot to mention it but my signals are digital so it might do it!

Answer (score 0):

What is called a "multiplexer" chip usually does the opposite (ie, pick one among several signals and direct it to its output).

So, the answer is "no".

Now, if you want to direct one signal to one (or many) outputs, you will have to decide if the signal is analog or digital, among other things. Since you don't say, we can't know.