# Multiplex IC 5 inputs and 5 outputs custom?

Tags: voltage, integrated-circuit, multiplexer, switching

Hey all I am wanting to know if there is an IC that allows me to do the following:

- Have 5 inputs
- Have 5 outputs
- Ability to take any input # and direct it to any output #

The latter bullet there is the main goal.

[image]

So in the image example above say that I needed the following examples:

> **Input 1** to output on **output 4**.
>
> **Input 3** output to **Output 1**.
>
> **Input 3** output to **Output 3**.
>
> **Input 4** output to **Output 1**.
>
> **Input 1** output to **Output 1**.
>
> **Input 2** output to **Output 5**.
>
> ...and so on....

What I would be hooking up to the input would be either Ground, 5V or 3.3V which would need to output the same as its input.

Note that I plan on using an Arduino so if the IC requires interaction from the Arduino in order to switch the outputs then I will have the means to do so.

**Update**

I will need to be able to use all of the inputs and outputs at the same time.

Example:

> Input 1 --> Output 4 (5v)
>
> Input 2 --> Output 1 (RX)
>
> Input 3 --> Output 5 (TX)
>
> Input 4 --> Output 2 (3.3v)
>
> Input 5 --> Output 3 (gnd)

Is there any IC that would allow me to do the above?

What I am looking to accomplish is taking this layout:

[image]

and connecting those pogo pins to the multiplex/demultiplexer/crossbar switch/cross point switch in order to allow for different pcb models that have different pin layouts in order to flash firmware to them using the FTDI.

Hopefully knowing that allows you to understand the overall design of what I am trying to do.

Comment: Asking for a product with a certain function is **Off topic**. And even if it wasn't, it is unclear what kind of signals you want to multiplex. Analog or digital, what current? How fast does it need to be. What will you connect at the input and outputs. Just saying Ground, 5 V or 3.3 V is insufficient, 3.3 V from a power supply and you want to power a circuit which needs 1 A at 3.3 V or...? Also try to find a similar solution yourself, like "this IC only has 2 inputs, is there a similar on with 5 inputs ?"

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie it’s perfectly fine for this type of question as it’s a (1) question and (2) needing an answer that can benefit others who are looking for guidance doing the same or similar thing.

Comment: @StealthRT yes, it may be a question that requires an answer, but it is still a product recommendation question, which makes it off topic here unfortunately

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In a multiplexer, can you direct the input into all the outputs at the same time?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/293013/in-a-multiplexer-can-you-direct-the-input-into-all-the-outputs-at-the-same-time)

Comment: @Andyaka that is not the same as my question above. That's **one input to many outputs** and not **many inputs** to **many outputs** as my question asks.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Please open up my question again. Thanks.

Comment: Nope, it's not just me voting to close this question. Asking to re-open the question is pointless. Instead, focus your energy on asking a proper question (meeting the rules) next time.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is a crosspoint switch.

Your question says that you want to pass 0 V, 3.3 V or 5 V signals through it. If this means LVTTL and TTL logic levels, with the output voltage remaining as the input voltage, you'd best use an analogue crosspoint switch.

I've previously used the ADG2188 8x8 device in a 32-pin package. There are other parts around but larger packages and higher costs come into play and you haven't stated your criteria there.

[image]

The ADG2188 input-to-output mapping is controlled through an I2C interface, rather than direct digital signals. As you'd need a lot of the latter, a serial bus like I2C is is to be expected.

Note that the ADG2188 requires a power supply rail that is 2 V higher than the largest voltage it is switching. In your case, it would need at least a 7 V supply to switch your 5 V signals.

Being an analogue crosspoint switch, it can carry any voltage in the range from its Vss supply pin voltage up to 2 V short of its Vdd supply pin voltage. Vss can go to 0 V if you're not carrying negative voltages, which you apparently aren't.

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge, Tony. I have updated my OP to add what I am looking to be switching.

Comment: Would the Crosspoint switch work even if its Analog for the RX/TX? The RX/TX/5v/3.3v/grd will be coming into the IC via a FTDI ft232r chip. Also most of these I've seen are either for Audio/Video or LVDS signals?